# P: con algoritmo de encriptado en c

Tags: c

Alguien sabe porque no me imprime bien esto? tengo que lograr imprimir **ovrbjrbvqcg** <--- "sería la frase BIENVENIDOS + 13 posiciones" y en lugar de eso me imprime **ovr  r vq**

el programa tiene que cambiar todas las letras, por ejemplo, la letra b (de b ienvenido), está en la posición 1, debo sumarle 13, es decir la b tiene que ser cambiada por la posición 1+13, es decir 14 (que es la o). Luego viene la letra i, está en la posición 8, entonces tiene que
ser reemplazada por la posición 8 + 13 que es la posición 21, es decir la letra v. Y así con todas las letras.

Desplazamiento vale 13;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void encriptar(char fras[50],char encrip[50]);

int main(void)
{

   char Frase[50] =  "bienvenidos";
   char encriptado[50] = " ";

   encriptar(Frase, encriptado);


   return 0;
}
void encriptar(char fras[50],char encrip[50]){

   char abc[24] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";


   int desplazamiento = 13;
   int palabra = 0;




   for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
       for(int j = 0;j<24;j++){
           if(fras[i] == abc[j]){
               palabra = j;
               
               printf("%c",abc[palabra+desplazamiento]);

           }

       }


   }

   printf("\nfrase ----> %s",fras);
   //printf("\nencriptado ----> %s",encrip);


}
```

Comment: No es necesario poner solucionado, con marcar la solución como aceptada alcanza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu cifrado es un **cifrado de tipo César**, donde la cadena se cifra mediante un desplazamiento de n letras en el alfabeto que usas que en tu caso es el alfabeto español, la forma de realizar este cifrado pudiera definirse como:

```
(posicionActual + desplazamiento) mod longitudAlfabeto
```

Donde longitud alfabeto es precisamente la cantidad de letras que tiene tu alfabeto y el módulo es para que si el la posición actual + desplazamiento excede la longitud de tu alfabeto pues este se reinicie, por ejemplo supongamos que tienes el **desplazamiento n = 1** y vas a encriptar la **letra z** que es la posición **25** cuando hacemos el desplazamiento vemos que no hay una letra **26**, por lo que el algoritmo no da el resultado esperado, ahí es donde entra el módulo ya que **26 mod 25 = 1** que es la **letra a**, que es en realidad lo que quieres obtener, teniendo esto en cuenta te propongo el siguiente algoritmo:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
   printf(%c, abc[(i + desp) % 25]);
}
```

Conté que tu alfabeto tiene una longitud de **25** letras, de todos modos si el valor es otro pues lo cambias.

Answer (score 3):

La cuestión es que el +13 (supongo que te refieres a ROT-13) no solo es sumar. Si la letra "se pasa" de largo (es "mayor" que `z`) hay que restar para que empiece desde el inicio del array.

Si tienes la letra `z` (posición 25) y le sumas 13, accedes a la posición 38 del array... que no está definida en tu array, y tienes *undefined behavior*.

La solución es usar la operación módulo (%) para encontrar el índice adecuado. Como tienes 26 letras, módulo 26 (recuerda que la `z` está en la posición 25). Así, si te sale que tienes que usar la letra 26 (la letra 13 + 13), que es la letra "después" de la `z`, al hacer `(i + 13) % 26` te da 0, que es la posición de la `a`).

```
printf("%c",abc[(palabra+desplazamiento)%26]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tengas varias observaciones, primero que ahora de ejemplo estas usando la palabra "bienvenidos" pero cuando cambies de palabras tendrás que volver a cambiar tu `función`... si quieres cambiar el sistema o la llave para *encriptar* dejar de usar el `[a-z]` y por ejemplo aumentar `[a-zA-Z]` entonces tendrás que volver hacer otros cambios adicionales en tu función y así si quieres considerar por ejemplo una llave distinta etc.
Lo que debes hacer es utilizar los tamaños de tu array de clave (tu `abc`) y el tamaño del string-array de la palabra que deseas codificar (`Frase`).

Lo que te va facilitar mucho el trabajo, finalmente te dejo el código con esas modificaciones para que veas lo bonito que funciona, además con comentarios de por que y que hace cada cambio.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// agregamos el parametro del tamaño del array de la Frase
void encriptar(char fras[], int lengthFras, char encrip[255]);

int main(void) {

   char Frase[] =  "bienvenidos";
   char encriptado[255] = " ";
   
   // calculamos el tamaño del array de la Frase length("bienvenidos") = 11
   int lengthFras = (sizeof(Frase) / (int) sizeof(Frase[0])) - 1;

   encriptar(Frase, lengthFras, encriptado);


   return 0;
}

void encriptar(char fras[], int lengthFras, char encrip[255]) {

   char abc[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";

   int desplazamiento = 13;
   
   // calculamos el tamaño del array del abc length("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz") = 25
   int lengthAbc = (sizeof(abc) / (int) sizeof(abc[0])) - 1;

   for(int i=0; i< lengthFras; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < lengthAbc; j++) {
           if(fras[i] == abc[j]){
               int index = (j + desplazamiento);
               // index puede pasar el tamaño del array abc (index > lengthAbc) lo que generaria un error
               // ya que en esa posición no existe valor, entonces para que suceda eso
               // realizamos la operación modulo (multiplo) del tamaño del arreglo abc (lengthAbc)
               // luego guardamos el resultado en encrip[]
               encrip[i] = abc[index%lengthAbc];
           }
       }
   }

   printf("\nfrase ----> %s", fras);
   printf("\nencriptado ----> %s", encrip);
}

// b i e n v e n i d o s
// o v r a j r a v q c g
```

Ahora puedes retirar la llave `abc[]` de la función en sí y colocarla como una variable global para un uso más practico, o hasta pasarla por parámetro desde `main()` previamente calculando el tamaño del array y luego mandar todo a la función `encriptar()`, y quedaría a tu mercer solo al momento de ejecutar tu programa mandar los parámetros de --palabra (`Frase[]`) y --lave(`abc[]`).

Suerte espero que te ayude.